# Error starting NPM .. Ghost Blog .. error npm start

Tags: node.js, github, gruntjs, npm, ghost-blog

********** Update *********
This had to do with me changing my ports to those of my ipaddress in config.js so I can test on mobile and table. Any idea how I can do this without changing the ports everytime I reboot the computer so that they are always set to my ipaddress for testing?

**********Original Question ****
 I am getting a strange error when starting npm to run my ghost blog. It has happened before and I went back to a previous commit on github. It seems like everytime I get it working through a different method and then stop working and close terminal. Then when I restart its another issues?? Maybe github is causing it. Any help would be great. Tried everything I know how to do.

here is the error message:

```
cconti77@Charless-iMac ~/sites/_repos/elite-university (get-back-on-it●●●)$ npm start
```

> ghost@0.5.0 start /Users/cconti77/Sites/_repos/elite-university
>   node index

```
Migrations: Up to date at version 003

events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1023:19)
at listen (net.js:1064:10)
at net.js:1146:9
at dns.js:72:18
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
at process._tickFromSpinner (node.js:394:15)

npm ERR! ghost@0.5.0 start: `node index`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ghost@0.5.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ghost package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node index
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ghost
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/cconti77/Sites/_repos/elite-university
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cconti77/Sites/_repos/elite-university/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using the Ghost port for something else.

Most probably ghost exited the wrong way, or you are using forever/pm2 and the process hasn't closed properly. try killing any 'forever/pm2' instances, then reboot your machine. Worked for me.

To understand what happens, I suggest you try the following to see which process uses the ghost port, then kill the process. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/

And also, you're a bit off-topic, this should be moved to SuperUser.